# read multiselected csv files in wpf datagrid using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

hey guys i been trying to read multi-selected csv files and display them in a wpf data grid but i am having problems with the code. here my code below

```
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
      [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    private class myCSVFile
    {
        public string Supplier;

        public string Product;

        public string Price;
    }
      private void btnImport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(myCSVFile));
        myCSVFile[] result= new myCSvFile[];

                 foreach (string filepath in ofd.FileNames)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Lenght; i++)
            {
                result[i] = File.ReadAllLines(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(filepath,".csv"));
            }
        }
        dtt.Columns.Add("Suplier", typeof(string));
        dtt.Columns.Add("Supplier Type", typeof(string));
        dtt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));

        foreach (myCSVFile c in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.Supplier + " " + c.Product + " " + c.Price);
            dtt.Rows.Add(c.Supplier, c.Product, c.Price);
            dataGridv.DataContext = dtt.DefaultView;
        }
        }
```

i have a file helper reference that i downloaded online to help read the .csv and this works for a single csv file but not for the multi selected. i used ofd.FileNames to get and array of paths and am trying to use a loop to readAlllines of a particular path but it gives me an error at

```
        result[i] =          File.ReadAllLines(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(filepath,".csv"));
```

it says cannot implicity convert type 'string[]'  to 'Spurs.Import.myCSVFile' please what am i doing wrong. is there another way to do this please am new to c#

Comment: Which version of C# are you actually using? Tagging multiple versions of c# is not useful and improper use of tagging

Answer (score 0):

1. You initialize `myCSVFile[] result = null;` thus `result[i] = ...` will fail.

   EDIT: In the updated question you initialze `myCSVFile[] result = new myCSVFile[];` which is invalid syntax. You must give the size of the array.
2. You traverse the FileNames collections twice in a nested loop

   ```
   foreach (string filepath in  ofd.FileNames) {
      for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Length; i++) {
          result[i] = //somestuff
      }
   }
   ```

   Thus `result[i]` will be assigned n^2 times, if you selected n files.
3. `File.ReadAllLines()` delivers an `string[]`. Each element of the array is on line in the given file. `myresult[i]` must be an Instance of `myCSVFile`. You will have to do some additional parsing of the filecontents to create such an instance.

   EDIT: I'm not sure, what to say on the parsing part, without knowing a file structure. But, to be honest, if you don't understand why you cannot assign a `string[]` to some custom class, we won't be able to help you here.

Comment: But still hâve the same error at file.readAllLine please what additional parse